# Why does my map of maps print all zeros?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I'm doing the following:

```
//d = 3701
//h = 3702
//c = 8
map<int, map<int,int> > table;
table[d][h] = c;
table iter = table.begin(); 
while(iter != table.end())
{
    cout << "d: " << iter->first << "h: " << iter->second[0] << "c: " << iter->second[1] << endl;
    iter++;
}
```

But my output is showing:  `d: 3701 h: 0 c: 0`

Comment: `iter->second[0]` doesn't exist before you call `cout`; suppose to call `iter->second[3702]` ?

Comment: Because `iter->second[0]` is getting the value of the inner map at `0`, likewise with the second one for `1`. Since neither of these exist, they're being allocated and assigned to the default value for int, `0`.

Comment: Oh, dang. For some reason I was assuming it would somehow magically know that I meant "the first and second *actual* element in this inner map". Thanks

Comment: So let's assume I didn't know the index value - how would I print out the inner map?

Comment: Put an inner `for` loop iterating over the inner map. I.E. `inner_iter = iter->second.begin(); inner_iter < iter->second.end()`, and then `inner_iter->first()` will be the key, and `inner_iter->second()` will be the value of the inner map at `iter->first()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only element on this map is with `key = 3701` and this is a map which has only `1` element with key `3702`, equal to `8`. If you try to access any other element like

```
iter->second[0] // inner map has no key = 0, so key = 0 with default value 
                // assigned to it is created

iter->second[1] // inner map has no key = 1, so key = 1 with default value 
                // assigned to it is created
```

`std::map` will insert default value to it.

If you want do avoid insertion of default values when checking if they are present you shoud use `find()` function to compare with `map.end()` iterator.

```
while( iter != table.end())
{
    cout << "d: " << iter->first;
    if ( (iter->second).find(0) != (iter->second).end())
         cout << "key 0, value: " << iter->second[0] << endl;
    ++iter;
}
```